# Remove space in between ImageButton elements in a Grid

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have to remove the white space between `ImageButton` in **Xamarin Forms 5**.

Right now I have placed the buttons in `Grid` cells. Each `Button` is in each cells.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the xaml you have written

Comment: @rauf if the answer below solved your issue accept it so that your post can better help other developers with similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

### The Fix

To control space between `Column`s in a `Grid` use the `ColumnSpacing` property.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.grid.columnspacing?view=xamarin-forms) states that this property controls

> The space between columns in this Grid layout. The default is 6.

### The Example

As an example take the following code

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
  <ImageButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
  <ImageButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
  <ImageButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
</Grid>
```

Which creates a three `Column`s `Row` with no space between the `Column` elements:

[image]